# Android: How can I programmatically draw text on key guard screen / lock screen?

Tags: android, wallpaper

Is there a way to draw on or modify the key guard wallpaper programmatically?

It looks simple enough for the home wallpaper, you can use WallpaperManager. But how about for the lock screen wallpaper? I would like to draw some text there.

Comment: Is there any way in new android release, can you please update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API to draw on the lock screen.

Comment: /There are apps that are doing this. How is it possible