# Android ICS native lockscreen

Tags: android, lockscreen

I've been looking for the past 2 days on SW, google and so on. I'm looking for a way to implement an activity that comes with the native Android ICS lockscreen as the one shown in the screens below.
Those screens come from [Player Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tbig.playerpro&hl=it) but I noticed that also other players ( [PlayerPro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tbig.playerpro&hl=it) for instance ) have the same feature that looks exactly the same, that's why i think it's something native or at least, there is a common way to implement it.

So far I only managed to get and Activity that replace the lockscreen using these flags:

- `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED`
- `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD`

with a BroadCaseReciever on these events:

- `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON`
- `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`
- `Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT`

My problem is that i want my activity to be shown with the lockscreen not replacing it. Do you guys know how to achieve this?

is there a native-hidden API to do this?

can you guys link me some sample that implement this particular feature?

thanks in advance ;)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: See this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065201/android-how-can-i-programmatically-draw-text-on-key-guard-screen-lock-screen

But, maybe since the 4.0 it's possible, else Player Pro use its own API

Comment: what do you mean with "its own API"? by the way also other players have the same feature ( PowerAmp for instance ) so i guess it's not something developed by the PlayerPro guys.

Comment: Is it maybe a dialog fragment using the show when locked flag?  EDIT: there also appears to be a FLAG_SPLIT_TOUCH that allows touches outside the window to be transferred to that window if it has the flag on... Seems like the combination of these two could allow it

Comment: well, I've tried and I can't get it working because I can't show a dialog from a BroadCastReciever, it gives this error "BadTockenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application". Do you know how to retrieve the lockscreen token? that would be the solution.

Comment: I also tried to use FLAG_SPLIT_TOUCH in my activity using the Dialog style but still, it doesn't work because as soon as I set "android:windowIsFloating" to true the activity is shown after the  lockscreen. And without it does't show in overlay of the lockscreen.

other ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the Audio Controls "remote view" (RemoteControlClient) API added in Android 4.0 (API level 14). I found [the `RemoteControlClient` API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html) in the Android developer docs that:

> enables exposing information meant to be consumed
>   by remote controls capable of displaying metadata, artwork and media
>   transport control buttons.

(It was linked off of [this page](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/RandomMusicPlayer/index.html).)

Note: I have never used this API myself, so I apologize if this does not work for you.

Comment: +1 This is definitely what he's looking for, and what he should use for native integration with the lock screen.

Comment: yeee... finally the answer i was looking for. +1 and bounty.
I knew there was an API but i couldn't find it. Thanks a lot I m so happy i can finally implement that lockscreen :D.

Comment: Note: Sample is no longer available in the Developer portal.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost doing it right. Keep doing what you do with the BroadcastReceiver. That's the way to go. For the Window, these are the flags you need to use:

- WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
- WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL

Do ***not*** use FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGAURD

What these flags do: SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED allows your activity to show up on top of the lock screen. FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL allows touch events that are not on your activity to go to the other activities, ie, allows the user to unlock the screen. FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD gets rid of the lock screen, so we do not use it.

Define this style in your res/values/styles.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.FloatingTranslucent" parent="android:Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

In your manifest, define your activity's style

```
<activity android:name=".SampleActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.FloatingTranslucent">
...
</activity>
```

What this does is makes your activity completely see through and *wrap content*.

Now, your activity should be on top of the lock screen, allowing touch input to the lock screen and to your app, with your activity not full size.

Cheers.

Comment: did you already implement it that way? because i tried and as soon as i put android:windowIsFloating to true i can't get the Activity to show on top of the keyguard, even if i set FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED

Comment: i also tried to put TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG as window type but nothing changed.

Comment: Hello @Zaid-Daghestani would you have a solution for this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466950/creating-a-real-lockscreen-module-for-android